# Fourier transform for 2 signals

Tags: digital-communications

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be $2$ signals of duration $T$ and bandwidths $B$ and $B'$ respectively, with $B<B'$.

Consider $s(t)=f(t)+g(t)$. With Fourier transform, we have $S(\nu)=F(\nu)+G(\nu)$ and the bandwidth of $s$ is $B$.

1. Is it correct in digital communication to add signals that do not have the same bandwidth?
2. With this sum, can one signal be masked by another? For example the hidden signal here would be $g(t)$ with a bandwidth $B'<B$ and with matched filtering $$\max_t \big(|\int_0^Tf(u)g^{\ast}(u-t)du|\big) \simeq 0$$.

Comment: Are the bandwidths overlapping?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the spectrum of each signal starts at 0:

> With the Fourier transform we have, $S(\nu)=F(\nu)+G(\nu)$

Correct

> and the bandwidth of $s$ is $B$.

Incorrect. The bandwidth would be the larger one, i.e. $B'$.

> Is it correct in digital communication to add signals that do not have the same bandwidth?

That's a strange question. Adding two signals is about as basic as it gets and happens all the time regardless of signal properties (including bandwidth). Whether it's "correct" depends on what you want to do and why.

> With this sum, can one signal be masked in another?

Unless the energy of one signal is much larger than the other, there will be no masking. A better way to think about it that, $g(t)$ is added noise for $s(t)$ and vice versa. Whether you can recover one or both depends on the details. There are plenty methods to do so, but they need a sufficiently large difference in signal properties to work with. The easiest ones being non-overlapping in frequency or time.